# CloudFlare Error on Page

Tags: joomla, cloudflare

I seem to be getting an error while using cloudflare on my domain. No matter what i do it won't go away, I've tried turning off various options in cloudflare and my joomla CP, using jbetolo for minification,merging and compression of js and css files.

the error is as follows: `Failed to Load Resource` `http://website.com/cdn-cgi/pe/bag?r[]=http%3A%2F%2Fwebsite.com%3A80%2Fcdn-cgi%2Fnexp%2Fv%3D1443929931%2Fapps%2Fga_key.js` `cloudflare.min.js:35`

I can't find any resources on this error. here is more output of the console reporting the error. Could anyone tell me why this happens, how to fix it, or if this is normal? Thanks.

`a.function.a.object.a.object.d.(anonymous function).object.d.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)cloudflare.min.js:37`

`a.function.a.object.a.object.d.(anonymous function).object.d.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)cloudflare.min.js:37`

browsing to the link returns a 405 Not Allowed error, I guess this is a little obvious.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone else looking for a solution, changing the "Rocket Loader" setting under the SPEED menu from "Automatic" to "Off" fixed the problem for me. While in "Automatic" mode, my JavaScripts were being wrapped in a CDATA block, which caused the error, but disabling the "Rocket Loader" removed the wrapper.

Note that you can still use JavaScript minification while turning off the "Rocket Loader".

[image: CloudFlare Rocket Loader]

The "Rocket Loader" at the time of posting is still in Beta mode, so it's possible that some bugs remain. It is unclear why one javascript file causes the problem, while others do not.

Answer (score 1):

That appears to likely being caused by CloudFlare's Auto Minify option. Did you turn this off?

Note: You don't want to have CloudFlare's minify turned on with another option (can definitely see issues).

[Contact CloudFlare](http://support.cloudflare.com/cgi/discussion/new) with the domain if turning off Auto Minify doesn't fix it & we can have an engineer check it out.

Comment: that didn't seem to work, i'm going to contact cloudflare soon. thanks.